# UE4 slow down if you add AActor to the TArray?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

There is an TArray in UInventoryComponent (UActorComponent) in which Items (AActors) should be stored. As soon as an Item is added to the array, UE4 begins to slow down more and more. What could be the reason?

Comment: What do you mean by slowing down?

Comment: A strong drop FPS. The more items in the array, the faster the FPS drop begins.

Answer (score -1):

Everything has been decided. The interface was called on the wrong event.